# Selected property MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

Struggling to learn MVVM in WPF here...

I'm using EF4.0 and have managed to bind a `DataGrid` to an `ObservableCollection` which is populated from a simple `LINQ` query.

I now want to bind a text box to a selected property from the grid view. For example I want my txtName `Textbox` to reflect the selected Name property in the `DataGrid`. I've gone down to a single column in my `DataGrid` to simplify things This is what I have so far:

XAML:

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding AssetTransList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTransaction}" Height="177" Name="dataGrid1" Width="869" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Block Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

 <Grid DataContext="SelectedTransaction">
            <TextBox Height="23" Name="txtBlockName" Width="120" Margin="61,8,671,55">
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="Block_name" UpdateSourceTrigger="Explicit">
                    </Binding>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
        <Label Content="Block Name" Name="label1" Margin="6,6,771,48" Target="{Binding}" />
        </Grid>
```

View Model:

```
 private tbAssetTransaction _selectedTransaction;
    public tbAssetTransaction SelectedTransaction
    {
        get { return _selectedTransaction; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedTransaction != value)
            {
                _selectedTransaction = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTransaction");
            }
        }
    }
```

The view model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` from a base class. In my View Model constructor I'm not sure how to extract the selected data...

Constructor:

```
class AssetTransactionViewModel : NotifyPropertyBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<tbAssetTransaction> SelectedAssetTransactions { get; set; }
    public AssetTransactionViewModel()
    {
        GetAssetTransactions();
        SelectedAssetTransactions = new ObservableCollection<tbAssetTransaction>();
        SelectedTransaction = SelectedAssetTransactions[0];
    }
```

The problem is my SelectedTransaction property is never set. The getter returns null and then the set method is never run therefore my textbox value is never set. I have under a year's programming experience so this is a little 'In at the deep end' for me. Thanks

Comment: where is your TextBox?

Comment: What problem you have? It's not clear.

Comment: whoops, edited XAML in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set binding `Mode` to be `TwoWay` in `DataGrid` so **SelectedItem** will be updated:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTransaction, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

..and change `TextBox` binding:

```
Text="{Binding SelectedTransaction.Name}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a textbox and bind the selected item.name to its text property
for example:

```
 <TextBox Height="23" Name="txtBlockName" Width="120" Margin="61,8,671,55" Text="{Binding SelectedTransaction.Name}">

        </TextBox>
<TextBox />
```